# Ubuntu 12.04 - compiz plugin - screenshot not catching the launcher menus

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, compiz

I have enable the following plugin that allows me to make a screenshot of selected by me area:

1. Screenshot plugin
2. Ubuntu 12.04

Unfortunately, I am not able to make a screenshot of my launchers sub menus (after right click of icon on the launcher a menu appears).

Actually, I have enable this plugin because I was not able to make a screenshot of this sub menus using the ordinary print screen button.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Change the delay from 0 sec to 4 or 5 seconds and then try.

[image: Screenshot of ScreenShot window]

Hope you got the reason why it was not working.